# weird __DIR__ behaviour

Tags: php, filesystems

So, I got this interesting effect today: I was running the following code from inside a file located in (f.e.) `/var/www/docroot/some/folder/`:

```
var_dump(__DIR__);
```

and it kept returning something like `/var/www/docroot/`.

I restarted apache, and then I even upgraded apache to the latest version, but still no luck. I then read in a post about trying to use `realpath` instead, and so I did:

```
var_dump(realpath(__DIR__));
```

and this indeed output the correct folder, `/var/www/docroot/some/folder/`

I then did again a

```
var_dump(__DIR__);
```

and again the correct folder `/var/www/docroot/some/folder/`, appeared.

Now, I know PHP caches some filesystem properties, but [the](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) doesn't seem to mention magic constants being cached, nor have I stumbled across this behaviour in the past. Does anyone know under what circumstances this may happen?

I was using PHP 5.5.28/apache 2.4.6 on Centos7

Comment: was it really in `some/folder`? You're working on the `some` project and are currently in the `folder` phase? Don't wanna be mean, but maybe the actual contents of your path matters, maybe it has funny characters in it, or what else. Can you reproduce the problem if you really put the files into `/var/www/docroot/some/folder/`, by really creating `some` and `folder`? What does `__FILE__` say?

Comment: similar thing happened to me working with nginx and php5-fpm, restarting php5-fpm fixed it for me.